# How can I use fork() and pipe() to create n child processes and accumulate user input?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, child-process

How to create n child processes from single process that returns the user input to their parent process and prints out the values gotten so far? Here is how it should look like, where n = 3:

```
(Main started.)
(Child 1 started)
(Child 2 started)
(Child 3 started)
(Child 3 input) So far: ''. Enter a string >>> a
(Child 2 input) So far: 'a'. Enter a string >>> b
(Child 1 input) So far: 'ab'. Enter a string >>> c
(Main) Result: 'abc'
```

In the above example, the user input `a`, then `b`, and finally `c`. The program should print out the accumulated letters after each input.

Note that this must be done using `fork()` and `pipe()`, and each child process (except for the last one) must be a parent to the process after it, as I plan to do other things with this. So for-loops won't do.

I've been reading up on the `fork()` and `pipe()` functions, but I still can't seem to create what I described above.

What I did so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("(Main started.)\n");
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
        printf("Error");
    }
    int id = fork();
    if (id == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        char x;
        printf("(Child 1 started)\n");
        printf("(Child 1 input) So far: ''. Enter a string >>> ");
        x = getchar();
        write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(char));
        close(fd[1]);
    } else {
        close(fd[1]);
        char y;
        read(fd[0], &y, sizeof(char));
        close(fd[0]);
        printf("(Main) Result: '%c'\n", y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
➜ gcc -o test main.c
➜ ./test
(Main started.)
(Child 1 started)
(Child 1 input) So far: ''. Enter a string >>> a
(Main) Result: 'a'
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried and where did you get stuck? Post the code.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli S'not a requirement as long as you don't post a duplicate, and is clear and concise.

Comment: @Steph It's not a requirement, but nobody is likely to do your homework for you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. The question is also _trivial_, so without knowing where you got stuck, it's hard to answer without just doing the complete homework assignment.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I see. I added my work. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I added the code, thanks either way.

Comment: You are reading an `int`, while the assignment asks you to read a string. Can you fix that first?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Roger that.

Answer (score 0):

In general your code looks reasonable/correct.

Try to write a subroutine:

```
void do_child(int child_no, char *output, size_t out_size) { ... }
```

Your `main()` would then become:

```
int main()
{
  char buf[1024];
  do_child(1, buf, sizeof(buf));
  printf("Main: %s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

In `do_child()` you would decide whether you need more children (`child_no < 3`), and if so use `pipe`, `fork` and `do_child` *again*.

Once you reach `child_no == 3`, you can just read the string from `stdin`, write it to `stdout`, and return.

The only other thing you need to do: children should no have to worry about where to write their output (they should all write to `stdout`). To achieve that, use `dup2` to redirect each child's `stdout` into an appropriate pipe.

Comment: Can the "do_child" call within itself be replaced with an execvp call?